# Oracle 11g to 12c migration gotchas?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am embarking on an 11g to 12c Oracle DB migration. I will need to do it at least twice, once for testing, a 2nd time fro production. My initial thought is to use expdp/impdp. I export "full" the DB nightly using expdp.

My problem in the past when importing a full DB is it can get squirrely regarding the system schema/users. A full import tries to muck with system schemas (sys, system, sysman...). My new 12c DB is a portable DB, and obviously I want none of the settings or data from the system schemas, that may hose my new DB.

I do however want all of the non system schemas and users, of which there are 5 or so real schemas, and 30 or so "users."

I have been looking for some blogs or documents that address this issue, and can't find any. A pointer to documentation on how to avoid the problems described above would be great.

Also if there are any other gotchas when doing the migration, a heads up on that would be useful as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, system schemas aren't part of the FULL export so - you shouldn't worry about that. Documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SUTIL/dp_export.htm#SUTIL826 says: "Several system schemas cannot be exported because they are not user schemas; they contain Oracle-managed data and metadata. Examples of system schemas that are not exported include SYS, ORDSYS, and MDSYS."

Comment: In the past maybe 8i or 9i (old export/import) I believe I had a problem where the DB went into a weird state after an import. I will try a "full" import and see what happens.

Comment: Good luck, by all means!